# Plotly generates same plots for different sets of data in a python for loop

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly's scatter plot function inside a for loop to plot multiple graphs.

The problem is, I am getting the same plots for all values of the loop which shouldn't be the case. Is there a way I can use a variable for filename and perhaps, also titles, axes labels?

Or should I clear the plot from memory before plotting a new one? I am thinking the filename is probably the culprit?

```
    for kp in all_phases_plot.keys():
        all_p_values = all_phases_plot[kp]

        phase_trace = go.Scatter(
            x=all_dates,
            y=all_p_values,
        )

        dataa=[phase_trace]

        py.plot(dataa, filename='each-phase-line')
```

I expect different plots when the loop executes but is not the case. They are all exactly the same!

Comment: You're overwriting that file every time you go through the loop. Figure out how to iterate the names. like filename = kp + ' each-phase-line'.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have similar issue here, 
I have 4 files inside a directory each having different values, when I am running my function (python plotly) in for loop for each file I am getting first graph as expected but after that rest three graphs are over lap, but I want 4 individual graphs with their on data only, ANY IDEA please